# What exactly does httpurlconnection.setReadTimeout() do?

Tags: java, timeout, httpurlconnection

According to the java docs of connection.setReadTimeout() -
"A non-zero value specifies the timeout when reading from Input stream when a connection is established to a resource. If the timeout expires before there is data available for read, a java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised. A timeout of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout."

So if I set a certain read timeout, and start downloading a file, will the download break if the timeout is reached?

Or does it break only when there is nothing to read for that specified timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's only raise exception if there is no response. It'll not break while getting data so don't worry about.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was worried about.

Answer (score 0):

If you start downloading the file and there is no interruption, the timeout will not occur.

If you have the timeout set to 30 seconds. If you're downloading for 15 seconds and after those 15 seconds, the connection fails, you will have to wait another 30 seconds before timeout.

Answer (score 0):

The read timeout starts afresh every time the `recv()` function is called.

So the correct answer is (2).